# MySQL Workbench left navigator panel missing on MAC?

Tags: mysql-workbench

I connected to the server in mysql workbench but I see that something has changed? There used to be a navigator panel on the left hand side with all the schemas and the database options like this:
[image]

But now on mine it only shows:

[image]

I have tried going to the preferences and clicking on all the options but nothing works???

[image]

Answer (score 139, accepted):

There's a splitter between the Object/Session info and the schema tree/management part. In your case it's moved up all the way, so you only see the lower part. Drag the marked line down to make the upper part visible:

[image]

**Update**

Starting with MySQL Workbench 8.0.14 the splitter has been changed to show in a different style which makes it much more easy to recognize it:

[image][image]

Comment: This helped me also but the secret is that once you see the cursor change, you don't just drag a few pixels down, rather you must move it down a significant amount ( several cm / inches ) and then Management and Schema will "pop" and suddenly appear all at once.