# How to view Schemas in MySQLWorkbench

Tags: mysql

I am trying to open my database on Macbook that I created but unable to see the schemas on the left side.
Anybody knows what the error might be and why I am unable to see the tables and schemas.

Thanks
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL Workbench left navigator panel missing on MAC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47645158/mysql-workbench-left-navigator-panel-missing-on-mac)