# Do not see tables in the MySQLWorkBench GUI

Tags: mysql-workbench, amazon-rds

I am attaching the image of what I see at opening MySQLWorkBench for a particular connection.  Previously, on the left pane I saw the expandable list of the tables, now I see the empty pane.
The change was in the username/password for standard TCP/IP over SSH connection method for connection to AWS RDS.
Is it possible to see the list of the tables again? Maybe I changed accidentally some MySQLWorkBench settings?
[image]

Answer (score 4):

I have MySQL Workbench 8.0, version 8.0.19 on my MacBook Pro. Try to hover your mouse in this area shown here (with the red arrow):

[image]

Then click, hold, & drag down to reveal the tables:

[image]

Comment: WHY would they hide that extremely important and key part of the interface like that? That is one of the DUMBEST UI decisions I have ever seen.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Edit and open Preferences

[image]

Select SQL Editor and check both options under sidebar. Click OK.

[image]

Hopefully, it will solve your problem. To answer this question, I took help from [here](https://www.got-it.ai/solutions/sqlquerychat/sql-help/general-sql/how-to-work-with-the-mysql-workbench-navigator/#:%7E:text=If%20the%20Navigator%20panel%20is,select%20the%20Show%20Sidebar%20option.)

Comment: I have a little different setup for MacOs Workbench. Still, checking "Show metadata and Internal Schemas" did not help

Comment: If this didn't help. Check the new answer I have added to this question

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47645158/mysql-workbench-left-navigator-panel-missing-on-mac/47649653). Their problem appears to be the same as yours.